# Justify text in FlowTextView

Tags: android, textview, justify

I'm using the library FlowTextView for wrapping TextView in Android. The text is wrapping around ImageView inside the layout. I want to justify the text but I don't know how can do this. I try with Html.fromHtml but it doesn't work.

Here is the code for layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal" 
   android:gravity="center">

  <uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView
     android:id="@+id/flowtv"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/imagePatrimonio"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
  </uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView>      
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code to set the text in FlowTextView:

```
FlowTextView flowText = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.flowtv);
flowText.setTextSize(27);
flowText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
Spanned spannable = Html.fromHtml("<html><body style='text-align:justify;'>" + strText + "</body></html>");
flowText.setText(spannable);
```

What can I do to justify the text in FlowTextView?

Comment: I've found this [library](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android)

Comment: Pamela Have you found solution for justifying text in flowtextview.. please help me ..i am stucked up on same..